# Проблемы с адаптивностью футера — Mozilla

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Половина футера плывёт в Мозилле, хотя в Хроме всё нормально отображается. А именно с правой половиной секции. Не могу понять, в чём проблема, может, надо для Мозиллы отдельно указать атрибуты?

```
<footer class="bg-footer">
    <div class="container shape">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 left-form-block">
                <h2>Напишите нам</h2>
                <h4>Мы будем рады вам ответить</h4>
                <div class="form-group style-form">
                    <input type="text" class="form-input" placeholder="Имя*">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group style-form">
                    <input type="email" class="form-input" placeholder="Email*">
                </div>  
                <div class="form-group style-form">
                    <input type="text" class="form-input" placeholder="Сообщение*">
                </div>  
                <button class="btn btn-danger">Отправить сообщение</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 right-form-block">
                    <img src="images/footer-logo.png" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                    <div class="box col-lg-offset-3 col-sm-offset-1">
                        <div class="map" id="map_canvas"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="adres-contacts-footer col-lg-offset-3 col-sm-offset-1">
                        <p>г. Москва, ул. Большая Бронная, д. 27/</p>
                        <a href="#">+38 (050) 575-19-06</a><br>
                        <a href="#">+38 (093) 390-39-79</a><br>
                        <a href="#">+38 (067) 443-35-42</a><br>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></i></a>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus fa-2x"></i></a>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-youtube fa-2x"></i></a>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>          
</footer>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: копать в сторону input - его размеры.

Comment: немного не понял

Comment: input поставить width: 100% Возможно поможет.